# Can Java be accurately described as statically and dynamically typed?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages, typing, type-checking

Java seems to be categorized as a statically-typed language [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), but I'm wondering if it would be accurate to describe it as generally statically-typed but having some dynamic typing because of the run-time type checks performed when downcasts are performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would be accurate.  Also, array writes involve a runtime type check, to deal with [problems associated with covariant array types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Covariant_arrays_in_Java_and_C.23).